# Error :- Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object magento

Tags: php, magento

I created new payment method in Magento . I got below  error in admin panel . 
( Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object). I googled finally I got only  bad solution (code change in core file ) .

```
 I need to fix the issue without change core file code .
   if(is_object($sourceModel)){
    $optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
   } else {
      Mage::log($e->source_model);
   }
```

Comment: Does this error appears in System Configuration?

Comment: yes, the error appeared in system ->configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From the provided information I could guess that you are missing source model for a select field in system configuration (or this source model is not specified correctly)

First check system.xml file for your module - each select field should have source model specified:

```
<fields>
    <my_select_field>
        <label>My Label</label>
        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
        <source_model>your_models_name/path_to_class</source_model>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
    </my_select_field>
</fields>
```

Second, Check if Source model class exists (and is named correctly).

As the example of source model declaration and implementation you can use "adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno" that points to app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Yesno.php

Pay attention that models location is configured in config.xml under f.e. global/models/your_models_name/class node

BTW, if your select is representing boolean setting, you can use "adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno" without implementing source model in your module.